# Ho do i add animation to a widget in a stateful widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget where i have a button that controls the visibility of a container, when this button is tapped, the container is shown, and when tapped again, the container is hidden.

How do i add animation so when the container is being hidden and visible it appear like a dropdown menu?

For clarification i will add both picture and code

Image:

[image]

Above image, when you tap the drop down button again, the content details is hidden.

Code :

```
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 22.0, right: 22.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Job details ',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Color(0xff34495E)),
                        ),
                        controller.isDropDownVisible.isFalse
                            ? IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    controller.toggleDropDownVisibility();
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.expand_more,
                                ),
                                color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                              )
                            : IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    controller.toggleDropDownVisibility();
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.expand_less,
                                ),
                                color: Color(0xff3498DB),
                              )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.1),
                    thickness: 2,
                  ),
                  controller.isDropDownVisible.isTrue
                      ? Container(
                          color: Color(0xffF5F5F5),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0, right: 22),
                            child: Table(
                              border: TableBorder(
                                horizontalInside: BorderSide(
                                  strokeAlign: 10,
                                  color: Color(0xff34495E).withOpacity(0.1),
                                ),
                              ),
                              defaultColumnWidth: const IntrinsicColumnWidth(),
                              children: [
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Title',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Asoebi Gown',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Quantity',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        '12',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Description',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Praesent vitae neque porta, hendrerit enim sed, temps ante. Suspendisse vitae massa neque. Praesent vitae neque porta, hendrerit enim sed, tempus ante.',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Phone',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        '09077338833',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Date to complete',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                            color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    TableCell(
                                        verticalAlignment:
                                            TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
                                        child: Row(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                          children: [
                                            Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                '05-03-22',
                                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                    fontSize: 12,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                    color: Color(0xff34495E)
                                                        .withOpacity(0.8)),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                    50, 151, 219, 0.09),
                                                borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                              ),
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  '15 days',
                                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                                      fontSize: 10,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w400,
                                                      fontStyle:
                                                          FontStyle.italic,
                                                      color: Color(0xff34495E)),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : SizedBox(),
```

This is my controller :

```
  final isDropDownVisible = false.obs;

oid toggleDropDownVisibility() {
    isDropDownVisible.value = !isDropDownVisible.value;
  }
```

I know nothing about flutter animations apart from `AnimatedContainer` but in this logic, i don't think i have to use `AnimatedContainer` and even if i do, i don't know how to implement it.

Lastly I would also need help removing the extra padding as seen in the image below after my divider when the visible container is shown.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the [ExpansionPanel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html) Widget. It will require you to completely rework your code though. It also needs the [ExpansionPanelList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html).
To be clear the ExpansionPanelList is a list of ExpansionPanels.

Comment: Thank you sir for this reply, can you help me with a written example with respect to my code, i have looked at the link you sent and i am having issues..because all i want to show and hide is a widget.

Comment: I would just throw your whole widget into the body of the ExpansionPanel while getting rid of any controllers and all the animation related stuff.

Comment: what about the `headerBuilder` and the bool to control if it is expanded or not?

Comment: Yeah it's just a bool that determines if it is down or not. Try writting a function that will toggle a bool and use that. The headerBuilder is just your Jobs Details String.